# Find RadListBox item by value, server-side

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I'd find a transfer specific items in a RadListBox in the codebehind. From what I've been able to find, `FindItemByValue` is a client-side function. Is there a server side equivalent?

Here's what I have right now, but `FindItemByValue` always returns null.

```
RadListBoxItem item = CompanyListBox.FindItemByValue(comp.ID.ToString());
CompanyListBox.Transfer(item, CompanyListBox, CompanyDestBox);
```

This seems like it should work, but I can't figure out how to get `FindItemByValue` to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either FindItemByValue or FindItemByText, is it possible that you're looking up the text rather than the Value, or that your listbox is empty because of a postback issue?

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listbox-working-with-items-server-side.html

Comment: Looks like it was a postback issue. I feel like it should have occurred to me to look for that. Thanks for your help!